# Understanding Effective Java deep copy example

Tags: java, copy, deep-copy, effective-java

In Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 11 one can find the following deep copy example:

```
public class HashTable implements Cloneable {
    private Entry[] buckets = ...;

    private static class Entry {
        final Object key;
        Object value;
        Entry next;
        Entry(Object key, Object value, Entry next) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }

        // Recursively copy the linked list headed by this Entry
        Entry deepCopy() {
            return new Entry(key, value,
                    next == null ? null : next.deepCopy());
        }
    }
    @Override public HashTable clone() {
        try {
            HashTable result = (HashTable) super.clone();
            result.buckets = new Entry[buckets.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++)
                if (buckets[i] != null)
                    result.buckets[i] = buckets[i].deepCopy();
            return result;
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new AssertionError();
        }
    }
```

I don't understand how this makes a deep copy: key and value are objects, therefore no primitive types. So to my understanding, using

```
// Recursively copy the linked list headed by this Entry
Entry deepCopy() {
    return new Entry(key, value,
            next == null ? null : next.deepCopy());
}
```

creates a new `Entry` with a reference to the key and value of the original `Entry`?

Doesn't a deep copy basically mean: go down until one reaches primitive types, then copy those to the clone?

Thanks for any hint on this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a "deep copy" in that changes to the original object's linked list (via `next`) will not be seen in the copy or vice versa. Compare that with the "shallow copy" which would be taken if the new object just copied the original `next` reference.

It's a shallow copy in terms of the key and value though - if those are mutable types and are mutated then yes, the mutation will be seen via both the original and the "cloned" version.

So ultimately, it's a deeper copy than the naive "copy all references" approach - but it's not a *fully* deep copy.

Comment: very clear answer, thank you! didn't know there's eep copy and fully deep copy. Also thanks to CapnSmack for his reply :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you create a deep copy, it is not enough to have the "same" entries in the new HashTable. You must create *new instances* for each of those entries. Otherwise, each table will hold a reference to the same entry object. Then, when someone modifies a value in the first table, it will also be modified in the secon table (the new copy).